# StartSSL cert doesn't work with Dovecot/OpenSMTPD

Tags: linux, security, ssl, certificate, dovecot

I've an issue with my StartSSL certificate.
When I try to use it to activate SSL encryption on Dovecot, I get the following error in my log when a client attempt a connection to the imap server :

```
dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 16 secs
```

However, I've followed this tutorial : [SSL how to: install ssl on Dovecot IMAP serer | ErlyCoder](http://erlycoder.com/97/ssl-how-to-install-ssl-on-dovecot-imap-serer) and my private key (without passphrase) and the certificate are present where they must be, so I don't understand why it doesn't work

In my dovecot.conf file :

```
ssl_key =   /home/mail/ssl/****.key
ssl_cert =  /home/mail/ssl/****.pem
```

The certificate file contains in this order :

- My certificate
- The sub.class1.server.ca.pem content from StartSSL
- The ca.pem content from StartSSL

OS : Debian 8

Thanks

Comment: The error message suggests that the key file is corrupt in some way.  I'm tempted to say, "paste the contents of the private key file so we can check", but that would be naughty of me.  Make sure the key file starts with exactly five ASCII dashes (not any "fancy" unicode variations thereof), the text "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" (without the quotes), then another five ASCII dashes, then a newline.  No other spaces or other shenanigans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to make my StartSSL certificate works with Dovecot and OpenSMTPD (5.4.2p1) :

For Dovecot, you need to concatenate the key and the certificate into a pem file - thanks @Alexus - and add these lines into your dovecot configuration file :

```
# blablabla
ssl = required
ssl_key =   </home/mail/ssl/dovecot.pem # Key
ssl_cert =  </home/mail/ssl/dovecot.pem # Certificate
ssl_ca =    </home/mail/ssl/ca-bundle.pem # Server Certificate Bundle with CRLs
# blablabla
```

See http://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration for more information.
The `ca-bundle.pem` comes from StartSSL

For OpenSMTPD, it's been a long time before I understand that it works perfectly :

I used Thunderbird to test connection to Dovecot & OpenSMTPD, however a "bug" affects Thunderbird and makes me think that OpenSMTPD had a misconfiguration :

https://github.com/OpenSMTPD/OpenSMTPD/issues/451

To use Thunderbird with OpenSMTPD, you must select STARTTLS for authentication to your smtp server, else you'll have this error when you're trying to connect :

```
Aug 26 22:06:47 asterix smtpd[5866]: smtp-in: New session 8b475ba3c3415a4d from host 37-161-XX-XX.coucou-networks.fr [37.161.XX.XX]
Aug 26 22:06:47 asterix smtpd[5866]: smtp-in: Bad input on session 8b475ba3c3415a4d: 500 5.5.1 Invalid command: Pipelining not supported
Aug 26 22:06:47 asterix smtpd[5866]: smtp-in: Closing session 8b475ba3c3415a4d
```

My smtpd.conf :

```
pki <hostname> key         "/home/mail/ssl/opensmtpd.key"
pki <hostname> certificate "/home/mail/ssl/opensmtpd.crt"
pki <hostname> ca          "/home/mail/ssl/ca-bundle.pem"

listen on eth0 port 25 hostname <hostname> tls pki <hostname>
listen on eth0 port 587 hostname <hostname> tls-require pki <hostname> auth mask-source
```

PS : Key and Cert are in differents files for OpenSMTPD, not in a .pem like Dovecot

Answer (score 2):

per that document that you provided, try to put just private key & certificate into `.pem` and use same for file `ssl_cert` and `ssl_key`.

following from my own system:

```
[root@j /usr/local/etc/dovecot/conf.d]# grep ^ssl_ 10-ssl.conf 
ssl_cert = </usr/local/etc/dovecot/alexus.biz.pem
ssl_key = </usr/local/etc/dovecot/alexus.biz.pem
[root@j /usr/local/etc/dovecot/conf.d]# grep ^- /usr/local/etc/dovecot/alexus.biz.pem 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
[root@j /usr/local/etc/dovecot/conf.d]#
```

Comment: Yeaah, it works, but just for Dovecot :(

I've modified my dovecot.conf file like you said (and adding "<" before files paths)

I just put an another line to complete my configuration (ssl_ca) with the file from StartSSL - http://www.startssl.com/certs/ca-bundle.pem

OpenSMTPD isn't compatible with .pem files, how can I do to configure it ?

Comment: For others, ensure your pem does not also include the certificate chain.